# How to retain whitespaces in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, tabs

I have some code like this

```
<select class="form-control input-xs inline"
     ng-model="delimiter"
     <option ng-repeat="i in delimiters" value="{{i.value}}">
        {{i.name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

and delimiters array is like this

```
delimiters = [
    {'name':'Pipe', 'value': '|'},
    {'name':'Comma', 'value': ','},
    {'name':'Tab', 'value': '\t'}
  ];
```

The problem is, delimiter gets correct value for comma and pipe but for tab, it gets null. Seems that angularjs removes whitespaces. How to fix it?

I tried ng-trim="false" but didnt work.
Now trying to add one more '\' to tab. So tab has value "\t"m but this way i get literal string of "\t". Is there anyway to convert this string back to tab?

Comment: Please define "The problem is, delimiter gets correct value for comma and pipe but for tab, it gets null". The ng-model is compiled correctly, and its value is `\t`, as you can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-f3urvu . Can you please clarify the issue?

Comment: i my case, the tab gives null. I dont know why. Now im trying to do it the other way. Setting tab = "\\t" so that output is "\t" (literally) and trying to convert the string "\t" back to a tab. So how to convert this "\t" to a tab. Please not the string "\t" is in literal form.

Comment: **What is giving null**? the ng-model? it's quite unclear right now. If you're trying to **display** `\t`, then of course you won't literally see `\t`, though the value is correct. Can you please clarify the issue?

Comment: ng-model binds the selected value to delimiter. When i print the value of delimiter, it is null when i select tab. Im trying to save the selected option in variable delimiter and pass it to backend, but in case of tab, im passing null.. may be angular trims whitespaces and delimiter doesnt get tab saved in it.

Comment: If you check the link I posted you, the binding works as expected. Do you have some additional code **before** processing the request? If that's null, there likely is something else happening.